# Does ScalarDB throw NoMutationApplied exception if a duplicate Put is executed

Tags: scalardb

I am using ScalarDB which adds ACID functionality to `Cassandra`. It seems that if I use a duplicate `Put` i.e. insert an entry which is same as an existing entry then `NoMutationApplied` exception is thrown.

Is this correct? Is there any other condition under which this exception is thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An execution of `Put` with conditions like `PutIf` will throw `NoMutationException` when the conditions aren't satisfied.

In that case, you can make a `Put` request with `PutIfNotExists` condition and execute it. If the entry exists, `NoMutationException` will be thrown and avoid to overwrite the entry.

Comment: Is this right `val putUser: Put = new Put(pUserKey, cUserKey)
      .forNamespace(keyspaceName)
      .forTable(tablename)
      .withCondition(new PutIfNotExists()).withValue(...)` I tried this but am still getting the error. Maybe I am not using it the right way.

Comment: is `putif` used by default?

Comment: The operation looks good. I'm wondering whether an entry with `pUserKey` and `cUserKey` exists or not. Can the operation be executed without error when there is no entry in the table?

If you don't use `withCondition()`, the put doesn't have any condition.

Comment: The overall operation works if I am making a new entry in the database. The operation involves several checks & entries among tables so to be honest, at the moment I am not sure where it is failing.

Comment: if withCondition is not provided then will an existing entry be overwritten?

Comment: Yes, it will be overwritten.

Comment: if default behaviour is overwriting then I shouldn't get the Exception at the first place because I wasn't using withCondition at all in my code! My original query was `val putUser: Put = new Put(pUserKey, cUserKey)       .forNamespace(keyspaceName)       .forTable(tablename)      .withValue(...)` I'll attach a debugger and figure out what might be wrong in my implementation.